# Android outofmemory error allocation

Tags: android, object, garbage-collection, arrays, out-of-memory

I've been playing around with Androids sample code *Bluetooth Chat*. I'm thinking about using it as a base for my own app but I keep running into outofmemory errors. Right now I have it set up to read tons of data from a bluetooth device at a pretty fast rate. The app changes the byte array it receives into a String but after a while I get the outofmemory error. Is the gc too slow in removing all the String objects it creates? How do I free up the memory of the String

[Bluetooth Chat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChat.html)

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the buffer
            String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
            // save the connected device's name
            mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                           + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

The `MESSAGE_READ` case is the one that runs tons of times. Also I'm converting the String into a Hex String. Is there a way to change the byte[] directly to a hex String which can save the precious memory?

Answer (score 0):

about out of memory errors: i have not the perfect solution but nullifying the variable after the last use might help the GC to speed up its process.

About byte[] to a string of hexes, you may try to iterate over the byte array and call `Integer.toHexString(...)` on each byte.